# How to download items using TfvcHttpClient class

Tags: git, c#-4.0, azure-devops

For one of our automation requirement we need to download a bunch of git repositories which are available under a team project in VisualStudio Online.
We are using the classes available under `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi` to retrieve the repository details and we could succeed here. Now we need to download each of the repository on to a local machine. I thought of using `TfvcHttpClient.DownloadItemZipAsync` to download entire repository as a zip file. Following is the code snippet I am using to download the repository

```
private async Task<Stream> DownloadRepo(Guid repositoryId, string repoUrl)
        {
            System.Threading.CancellationToken cancelToken = new System.Threading.CancellationToken();
            TfvcHttpClient client = new TfvcHttpClient(new Uri("https://myproject.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/"), Credentials);
            var file = await client.DownloadItemZipAsync("$/", new TfvcVersionDescriptor()
                {
                    VersionOption = TfvcVersionOption.None,
                    VersionType = TfvcVersionType.Latest
                }, cancelToken);

            return file;
        }
```

But here I am not clear on how to pass the TeamProjectId and the repository Id so that the api can download the repository details.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool to manage Git repositories in TFS, namely [TfsGitAdmin](https://github.com/giuliov/TfsGitAdmin). You need to grab the `GitRepositoryService` from the Collection object and ask via the [`QueryRepositories` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.git.server.teamfoundationgitrepositoryservice.queryrepositories.aspx) info on available repositories.

Would be nice if you fork and extend my code to support your scenario , so other may benefit.

Comment: Thanks Giulio for your response. But I resolved the problem using a REST call after querying all Git Repositories.